# Error al descargar un video de Youtube con Python

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

Estoy tratando de descargar un video de youtube en otro tipo de calidad con la libreria pytube, pero me sale el error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'download'` Como si no existiera el video en esa resolución. Gracias de antemano.

```
from pytube import YouTube

print("Descargando...")

YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cwutKsl-r-U").\
    streams.\
    get_by_resolution("480p").\
    download("F:/Pytube")

print("Descarga exitosa :)")
```

Comment: ¿ Has considerado la posibilidad de que realmente el vídeo no sea accesible en esa resolución ? [La documentación](https://python-pytube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#streamquery-object) es bastante clara: `Returns: The Stream matching the given itag or None if not found`.

Comment: Creo que ese vídeo tiene más de un _stream_ con la resolución "480p". Si pruebas con otra funciona. Podría ser fallo del módulo.

Comment: @Juanjo qué recomendaciones me podrias dar? He usado programas de descarga de videos en donde me aparece que tipo de calidad de video quiero descargar. Se me hace extraño que con python no se pueda lograr descargar un video en otro formato.

Comment: @Juanjo, otra solución que se me vino  a mi mente es consumir servicios web donde proporcionen la descarga de videos en otro formato. Pero actualmente desconozco si hay algunas presentes.

Comment: Me pasa lo mismo y tampoco eh dado con la solución es como algún problema de la librería ya que a veces me descarga en 720 y a veces no donde me sale ese problema en otras resoluciones no cuando el video con el que pruebo tiene 480, 360 y las demás

Comment: sale ese error por que se retorna None ese puede ser por que tal vez esa calidad no esta disponble para la descarga. Por otra parte esto no es una respuesta, por favor lee [answer] para que sepas como elaborar una respuesta y te pediría que elimines esta publicación ya que puedes recibir votos negativos

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal otra opción sería usar `YouTube-dl`. He revisado y pytube parece que no está siendo actualizado y tiene algunos problemas, por lo que en mi opinión, optaría por cambiar el código ó "mirar cómo en pytube" pueda obtener las resoluciones disponibles de descarga de un video dado...